# Possible to do VLOOKUP as a udf in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's take the following:

[image]

The pseudo-sql for this would be:

```
SELECT
   Name,
   Age,
   VLOOKUP(Name, OtherTable, Letter)
FROM
   Table
```

I suppose the inefficient way to write this as a function would be something along the lines of the following scalar subselect:

```
VLOOKUP(TargetTable, TargetLookupField, TargetLookupValue, TargetReturnValue)
--> SELECT TargetReturnValue FROM TargetTable WHERE TargetLookupField=TargetLookupValue
```

Would a better way be doing a query-rewrite to pushdown the scalar subselect to become a join instead? Is that a common technique in query rewriting? And is BigQuery (or any other RDBMS) ever smart enough to detect that and be able to do that on its own?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but DBMSs have query optimisers that will re-write the SQL passed to it in order to execute it in the most efficient way it can determine

Comment: I'm sure he does know it.  @david542, I think I will have to dust off my copy of Access and see what the explain says for DLOOKUP (if access even has explain)

Comment: You can define the vlookup with a `right join`, for instance. But I don't think you can send the table name in the parameters. You you are asking about the optimization, comparing the scalar subselect and a join, the execution time will be different, I suppose the query is not automatically optimized in this case. Is that what you are asking for ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva it would be a `left join`, from the data table to the lookup. Otherwise, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

So, the best way to perform it from the beginning would be using a `join`, but, the [`UDF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) will  work.

I've compared both ways for you as exemplification:

##### 1-Implementing `VLOOKUP` with an `User Defined Function` (Not recommended):

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION VLOOKUP_SCALAR(user string)
AS (( SELECT letter FROM `data_letter` WHERE name=user));

SELECT name, VLOOKUP_SCALAR(name) as vlookup  FROM `data`;
```

##### 1-Result (More steps, time and bytes shuffled):

[image]

##### 2-Implementing `VLOOKUP` with a `JOIN` (Recommended):

```sql
SELECT t1.name, letter 
 from `data` AS t1 
LEFT JOIN `data_letter` AS t2 
 ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

##### 2-Result (Less steps, time and bytes shuffled):

[image]

Comment: @ewertonsilva -- thanks for this. Why can't BigQuery perform this optimization on its own, or is there not really a query optimizer in BQ?

Comment: -- also, it would be a `left join`. The vlookup goes from the data table to the lookup table, not vice-versa.

Comment: BQ does have it, as other databases systems, but in this case, you are explicitly asking the db to execute a UDF on each data row returned, that's not a case that can be identified and optimized. Query optimization is also a programming logic behind the scenes, so, there is no magic and the situations for the optimization has to be predictable.

Comment: I've eddied the answer to correct the query. thanks